# Google Maps iframe not displaying correctly with Bootstrap Collapse panel collapsed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, google-maps-embed

This should show exactly what I am struggling with:
http://jsfiddle.net/PaulHighten/c5knqdgd/

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingParis">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseParis" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseParis">
          Eiffel Tower, Paris
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseParis" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingParis">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="googlemap">
          <iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=Eiffel%20Tower%2C%20Avenue%20Anatole%20France%2C%20Paris%2C%20France&key=AIzaSyAFUKSu28KvFk67YcSlUWeUJ2TpcifSVmQ"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingLondon">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseLondon" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseLondon">
          Trafalgar Square, London
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseLondon" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingLondon">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="googlemap">
          <iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=Trafalgar%20Square%2C%20London%2C%20United%20Kingdom&key=AIzaSyAFUKSu28KvFk67YcSlUWeUJ2TpcifSVmQ"></iframe>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Paris panel shows the map correctly as it has a class of "in".

The London panel does not have that class which means bootstrap applies display: none; to that panel.  I'm assuming that stops the iframe from running it's http request properly.

Can the Google Maps Embed API be used to achieve this?  I've seen lots of questions relating to API v3 and initialize() calls, but struggled to find anything that related to making the embed iframe code work.

Thanks in advance.

=================

Edit: Code I used which solved the problem (slight modification of Christina's answer to only update the relevant iframe once):

```
$('[data-toggle="collapse"]').click('show.bs.collapse', function() {
  var mapFrame = $($(this).attr('href') + ' .googlemap iframe');
  if (!$(mapFrame).hasClass('map-refreshed')) {
    mapFrame.attr('src', mapFrame.attr('src')+'');
    mapFrame.addClass('map-refreshed');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refresh the iframe source on the shown.bs.collapse OR show.bs.collapse function

```
$('[data-toggle="collapse"]').click('shown.bs.collapse', function() {  
     var googleIframe = $('.googlemap iframe');
      googleIframe.attr('src',googleIframe.attr('src')+'');
});
```

### DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/ekba9y8w/

Assumes that the .googlemap is parent of the iframe.

### Paul Highten's update so it doesn't keep on refreshing:

```
$('[data-toggle="collapse"]').click('show.bs.collapse', function() {
  var mapFrame = $($(this).attr('href') + ' .googlemap iframe');
  if (!$(mapFrame).hasClass('map-refreshed')) {
    mapFrame.attr('src', mapFrame.attr('src')+'');
    mapFrame.addClass('map-refreshed');
  }
});
```

Comment: This worked great, although I made a slight modification so it only updates the map in the panel we are opening rather than all .googlemap iframes.  Code I used shown in edit to my original question.

Comment: Updated the code a little further to set a class to iframe's parent so I could check if the panel is opened a second time and not refresh the iframe again.

Comment: @PaulHighten - that rocks. Your fix helped me with a problem I had with livequery. I used that to check if :visible so it would work with both the collaps, tabs, and the tab-collapse plugin and any map hidden but it kept on refreshing when you clicked again.

Comment: @PaulHighten -- look at this code http://jsbin.com/gekuwo/1/edit?html,js -- the initialization is below the livequery plugin. It's working on my end, any suggestions, changes, etc.,

Comment: nice demo ... just wish the map refresh was a little less clunky.